# Is there a way to get file structure from azure blob?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm new to Azure and playing around with blobs in my .Net application.

I want to be able to get structure with folders, subfolders and files inside.

For now I've figured a way to get the files from all folders and subfolders altogether with parents. 
Is there any way to get folder structure some other way than parse Prefix of those files' parents?

File structure is the following:

```
root container
 -folder1
   -subfolder1
       -file
       -file
   -subfolder2
       -file
   -file
 -file
```

I've tried this, but it only gives me folder in the root directory, no subfolders:

```
            //returns account, client and container
            var blobData = GetBlobDetails(blobConnectionString, rootContainerName); 

            var rootContainer = blobData.Container;
            var blobList =  rootContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(string.Empty, false, BlobListingDetails.None, int.MaxValue, null, null, null);

            return (from blob in blobList.Result
                    .Results
                    .OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>()
                select blob).ToList();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a list of all folders in an container in Blob Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205153/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-folders-in-an-container-in-blob-storage)

Comment: @PeterBons I've tried it and didn't get subfolders

Comment: But in your code example the second argument, which is bool, is false. It needs to be set to true to get all blobs. There is no such thing as a folder or directory in azure blob storage, it is all based on the prefix. It is a virtual structure.

Comment: I tried that, with true parameter I get only files

Comment: Correct, as there **don't exist** folders in azure blob storage. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list#flat-listing-versus-hierarchical-listing)

Comment: @PeterBons I understood that folders are just representation in the blob storage and they don't physically exists. That's why I asked my question.

Comment: take a look at my answer. This should give you what you are looking for. As for your question: Since folders do not really exists, no, there is no other way than to traverse the prefixes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all, as noted in the comments: Blob storage does not know the concept of folders. Is all a flat structure and what you see below as prefixes, is all part of the path of a blob (=file).

That said, you can replicate the behavior by traversing the prefixes:

Using `Azure.Storage.Blobs 12.2.0`

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

namespace BlobLister
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get a connection string to our Azure Storage account.
            string connectionString = "*****";
            string containerName = "mycontainer";

            Console.WriteLine($"Recursivly listing blobs and virtual directories for container '{containerName}'");

            BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
            await ListBlobsForPrefixRecursive(container, "", 0);
        }

        public static async Task ListBlobsForPrefixRecursive(BlobContainerClient container, string prefix, int level)
        {         
            string spaces = new string(' ', level);
            Console.WriteLine($"{spaces}- {prefix}");
            await foreach (Page<BlobHierarchyItem> page in container.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(prefix: prefix, delimiter: "/").AsPages())
            {
                foreach (var blob in page.Values.Where(item => item.IsBlob).Select(item => item.Blob))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{spaces} {blob.Name}");
                }
                var prefixes = page.Values.Where(item => item.IsPrefix).Select(item => item.Prefix);
                foreach (var p in prefixes)
                {
                    await ListBlobsForPrefixRecursive(container, p, level + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote, but it probably does not hurt to mention that there is no notion of a physical folder structure. You won't be able to get a folder item for example.

Comment: This was very helpful; Microsoft's example-free documentation is so opaque that I wasn't even sure this was the problem it was solving.

Comment: glad it did - keep upvoting :)

Comment: Whilst this is a great solution, I'm going to warn others that this should be used cautiously when dealing with decades worth of stored data. Depending on the architecture recursively mapping a containers folders and files will absolutely tank the system let alone user experience as I've just found out. Still got an upvote though as it does exactly what's requested.

Comment: Yep, you are totally right there. But I would say the same is true for any bigger file store ;) Listing all files on your NAS share might also not be the best idea :D

Comment: Official Microsoft Documentation how to read the hierarchical structure with both V11 and V12 of the SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet11#use-a-hierarchical-listing