# How to download files from Folders inside Azure Blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I would like to know how to download files from folders that are created inside azure blob. A schematic diagram is shown below:

MyContainer (Container) --> **HomeFolder--> Sample.txt (Blob)**

If There is no folder and only sample.txt file is there, then I am able to download the file, but not when the file is inside a folder.

On stackeoverflow, I see most of issues are related to file directly under container. Could any one guide me on above request?

2) Another question is I want to do it via latest azure sdk [Azure.Storage.Blobs], but it would be fine if someone is using [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob] dll.

Below code that I am currently writing with [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob] class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string storageAccount_connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccount_connectionString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("lbdemocontainers");
        string blobPrefix = null;
        bool useFlatBlobListing = false;
        var listOfFileNames = new List<string>();
        var blobs = container.ListBlobs(blobPrefix, useFlatBlobListing, BlobListingDetails.None);
        //var folders = blobs.Where(b => b as CloudBlobDirectory != null).ToList();
        //foreach (var folder in blobs)
        //{
        //    var blob = (CloudBlockBlob)folder;
        //    blob.FetchAttributes();
        //    listOfFileNames.Add(blob.Name);
        //}
        //var downloads = blobs.Select(blob => blob.Uri.Segments.Last()).ToList();
        var blobNames = blobs.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

From above code it provides me Folder name `HomeFolder/` only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at my recent answer here. It goes recursively through a blob container. Note: there are no folders in blob storage! It's all part of the blob path. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715478/1537195

Comment: Thanks @silent , Here is how I did the same including downloading files in structured way. : https://github.com/Chandan-Baba/WorkingWithAzureStorage/blob/master/Program.cs