# Azure web app/site showing azure storage Container content

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I have a storage account in Azure where, in particular, I have a container storing some data, with new records added every now and then.

I would like to have a very simple website (web-app?) where users could see:

1. in the most basic version - simply the whole content of this
   container (i.e. all records)
2. in a less basic version - e.g. top 10 most recent records (they have a timestamp) from this container

Intuition tells me that at least for the 1st variant there should be something pretty much "ready" by default in Azure? Whereas I expect the 2nd variant requires some coding.

Could anyone please advise on a quick win here?

Comment: see my answer here on how to list the entire container https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715478/1537195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward, what you need to use is the Azure Storage SDK and use the method to [list the blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#list-the-blobs-in-a-container) or you can use the REST API

for the 2nd scenario you just need to order the files based on the updated timestamp and get the top 10 as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266792/getting-the-latest-file-modified-from-azure-blob)

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm a complete noob to web apps, do I understand correctly that a "structured" way forward would be 1. To understand first how to deploy to Azure a super basic "Hello world" app (I'll probably use flask/django; saw some good MS tutorials on how-to). 2. Use the API you reference in you answer to actually get the data from the storage into the website?

Comment: To answer my own question: yes, this the structured way to approach this.