# How to download a file (inside an other folder) from Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, containers, blob, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I need to download a file from Azure Blob storage.
But the file inside another folder. For example;

**Blob Containers** 
---***myBlobContainer*** 
-----TestFolder1
-------TestFolder2
-----------aaa.jpeg

I want to download aaa.jpeg file. I can download it when the situation like below;

**Blob Containers** 
---***myBlobContainer*** 
------aaa.jpeg

How can I navigate through the folders, I cant give a path to the file.
Thanks

Comment: May you please give additional information, error, how are you trying to download the file(code or Azure Portal)?

Comment: first: there are no folders in blob storage. but take a look at my older answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714051/is-there-a-way-to-get-file-structure-from-azure-blob/59715478#59715478

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no folders when using Azure Storage Account. You have a container, and all the rest is part of the blob name.

e.g.

myBlobContainer/TestFolder1/TestFolder2/aaa.jpeg

myBlobContainer is the container name

/TestFolder1/TestFolder2/aaa.jpeg

is the blob name

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#blob-names

An easy way to double check this, just loop over all the blobs inside a container, you can confirm the 'sublevels' are part of the blob name

```
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, container);
blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
Console.WriteLine("Listing blobs...");
// List all blobs in the container
var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs();
foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobs)
{
     Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
}
```