# How to get only folder name in blob using new Azure.Storage.Blobs namespace

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

[image: Snapshot]

I want to get all the folder name under a container using new SDK - Azure.Storage.Blobs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205153/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-folders-in-an-container-in-blob-storage

Comment: @Sajeetharan...The answer you linked makes use of older SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to use [`GetBlobsByHierarchy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsbyhierarchy?view=azure-dotnet) method in [`BlobContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet) class and pass "/" as prefix. The method will return all the blobs and folders at the root level. Once you get that, you will simply need to filter out the blobs by selecting only the items from the result where `IsPrefix` property is true (or you could check for `Blob` property to be `null`).

Please try something like the following:

```
        var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account-name>;AccountKey=<account-key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;";
        var containerName = "test";
        var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
        var blobFolders = containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchy(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, "/").Where(b => b.IsPrefix).ToList();
        for (var i=0; i<blobFolders.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Prefix: " + blobFolders[i].Prefix);
        }
```

Comment: I don't know if this was working back in 2020 but today it is not. Given the following structure:
```
/Folder/File1.txt
/File0.txt
```
Passing "/" to GetBlobsByHierarchy returns an empty enumerable. 
Passing "" returns or null returns everything (while the expected behavior would be /Folder and /File0.txt, not /Folder/File1.txt

Comment: @John - Please ask a new question and provide all the details there. AFAIK, the same code should work.

Comment: I think I found what the issue is. in your code above "/" is not passed as the prefix as your answer states. If you take a look at the method signature, the way you are calling it it is passed as delimiter. And indeed when passing an empty prefix with delimiter "/" I am getting the expected result.