# Azure Datalake Storage list first level of directories in container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a container named `foo` and a couple of directories in it with the following hierarchy:

```
foo\dir1
foo\dir2
...
```

How can I retrieve only the `dir1 & dir2` directories? Currently I'm using `Azure.Storage.Blobs (12.9.1)` library.

What I've tried:

```cs
      var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("foo");

      var resultSegment = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs().AsPages();
      IList<string> blobs = new List<string>();
      foreach(Azure.Page<BlobItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
      {
        foreach(BlobItem blobItem in blobPage.Values)
        {
          blobs.Add(blobItem.Name);
        } 
      }

      return blobs;
    }
```

This returns recursively all files that I have in the `foo` container. I need to mention that this is a hierarchical namespace storage, and I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61189867/how-to-get-only-folder-name-in-blob-using-new-azure-storage-blobs-namespace) solution but it doesn't work because each directory is considered to be a blob I think

Comment: You should be able to use a prefix. something like that should work `blobContainerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: "dir1")`

Comment: Yes but I do not know of `dir1` initially. I only know the name of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but I do not know if this is the best one. When another solution will appear I will delete this.

So in a hierarchical storage account (data lake) even a directory is considered to be a *blob* if I got it correctly. In that case, I observed that the directories have the `contentLength = 0` and `contentHash` is a `byte[0]`. With these assumptions in mind I managed to do the following:

```cs
      var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("foo");

      return blobContainerClient.GetBlobs()
        .Where(b => b.Properties.ContentLength == 0 && b.Properties.ContentHash.Length == 0)
        .Select(b => b.Name)
        .ToList();
```