# How can i get number of folders and files or name of folders and files at each level inside a blob storage of azure

Tags: python, azure

I have a storage account "STR_acc" inside it I have a blob "data_store". it contains multiple folder and subfolder with files. I need to count the files and folder present and if possible cumulative size of files. Is there any function to do that. In databricks i had dbutils though.

I did

```
STORAGEACCOUNTNAME = "STR_acc"
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = "some_key"
CONTAINERNAME = "data_store"

MY_CONNECTION_STRING2 = """DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName= ---whatever"""
blob_service_client =  BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(MY_CONNECTION_STRING2)
```

now i useed

```
container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
```

but i couldnt see any useful function

One idea is if i get the folders list, i can count them using len() function but cant find any

Comment: You can refer to [How to get a list of all folders in an container in Blob Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205153/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-folders-in-an-container-in-blob-storage/44207193) and [How to Count The Occurrences of a List Item in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/count-occurrences-of-python-list-item-e87782d8954c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the count the files and folder present based on the following logic . But am not sure getting the size of the file or folder , that options is available with azure now .

```
from azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice import BlockBlobService
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='storage-account-name', account_key='access-key')
containers = blob_service.list_containers()
for c in containers:
    <apply your own logic>
```

[image]